# How to fix plotly graph that shows data when in plotly but appears empty when run with dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm setting up a `dcc.Graph()` object in dash and setting the figure to a scatter plot that i created in `plotly`.

The plot displays all of its data exactly as I would like when in `plotly`, but when i run the local server and look at the plot in dash, everything is blank except for the axes and tick labels.

I have tried the following
- Edit the width and height in layout
- Created a dash server with only the graph object
- run the graph alone
- looked at the graphs representation on plotly's home site

The data for other graphs works and shows in the same dash, but not this one.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

def create_tile_scatter_plot_figure():
    def data_to_plotly(x):
        k = []
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            k.append(x[i][0])
        return k

    tiles = ['ALAÏA Vienne Laser-Cut Leather Tote',
             'AZZEDINE ALAÏA LASER-CUT KNITTED DRESS',
             'NEOPRENE SNEAKERS',
             'GRIP JACKET BLACK',
             'ORBIT PANT BLACK',
             'BLACK SHELL, MULTI FOX FUR',
             'LEATHER JACKET', 'LAUREN RALPH LAUREN Turtleneck Sweater',
             'Edwart Paris',
             'SG VARSITY POM BEANIE DARK BLUE',
             'Pro Longwear Foundation',
             'CHOCOLATE EYE PALETTE',
             'ALAÏA Laser-Cut Ankle Boots',
             'Mac 12 Lash',
             'Bobby Brown BUFF A Beige Pink Lipgloss',
             'ALAÏA Bracelet Leather Bucket Bag',
             'Bar 8 Mandarin Oriental Hotel',
             'Mandarin Hotel Paris', 'Grand Palais Paris']
    x_data = np.array([i + 1 for i in range(len(tiles))]).reshape(-1, 1)
    y_data = np.array([383, 367, 320, 318, 327, 420, 377, 303, 283, 302, 264, 257, 296,
                       317, 335, 302, 292, 297, 264]).reshape(-1, 1)
    tickvals = [i + 1 for i in range(len(tiles))]

    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x_data, y_data)

    p1 = go.Scatter(x=data_to_plotly(x_data),
                    y=y_data,
                    mode='markers',
                    marker=dict(color='black')
                    )

    p2 = go.Scatter(x=data_to_plotly(x_data),
                    y=regr.predict(x_data),
                    mode='lines',
                    line=dict(color='blue', width=3)
                    )

    layout = go.Layout(title='Engagement by Tile',
                       paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                       plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                       width=1300,
                       height=800,
                       xaxis=dict(ticks='',
                                  ticktext=tiles,
                                  tickvals=tickvals,
                                  showgrid=False,
                                  showline=True,
                                  showticklabels=True,
                                  automargin=False,
                                  range=[0, len(tiles)+1]),
                       yaxis=dict(ticks='',
                                  showgrid=False,
                                  showline=True,
                                  showticklabels=False,
                                  automargin=True),
                       showlegend=False,
                       hovermode='closest')

    return go.Figure(data=[p1, p2], layout=layout)
```

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(id='main-container', children=[
    dcc.Graph(id='scatter-regression', figure=create_tile_scatter_plot_figure())]),
    ])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I expect for the data to appear on the graph when in dash, but am unable to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your y-coordinates have the wrong format. I suggest you flatten them in your scatter creation, so you change:

```
y=y_data
```

to

```
y=y_data.flatten()
```

and

```
y=regr.predict(x_data)
```

to

```
y=regr.predict(x_data).flatten()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved it! I appreciate your help greatly